# How to limit gesture recognizer within a specific view

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, ios6, uigesturerecognizer

I have one imageView set up and I have added a `UIView` on that imageView. The `UIView` is transparent, Now I am adding some more `ImageViews` on that `UIView` dynamically.

I want set up Pan and Pinch Zoom gesture recognizers on that ImageViews that I am adding dynamically, but I dont get how can we limit the gestures recognizers operating range.?

When the image that is dragged using the Pan gesture,It should remain within that `UIView` and must not be dragged out of the borders of that `UIView`.

My `UIView` covers only half of the screen.

Any ideas on how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you will have to make condition in your pan gesture method

```
 CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:your view];

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    firstX = [your image center].x;//firstX and FirstY is CGFLoat...
    firstY = [your image center].y;
```

}

```
if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
 }
translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    if(translatedPoint.x < 0 || translatedPoint.x > 320)
    {
          set your image frame
    }
    else if(translatedPoint.y < 0 || translatedPoint.y > 480)
    {
        set your image frame

    }

     //   [your image setCenter:translatedPoint];

  you can change  boundaries in above conditions
```

Let me know if it is working or not...!!!
Happy Coding.!!!!

Comment: Hey, Thanks but I achieved it using touchesMoved method. :)